# How to count dropdown choices at a form

Tags: java, javascript, pdf, drop-down-menu, count

I know this is simple, but I don't know much about JavaScript and I can`t solve this.

I have a PDF Form with 71 dropdowns. Each has 4 different options. I`ve already put the export value of each option, however I can not make a text field that will count how many of export value 1 (for example) has been choosen.

How can I write this with JavaScript?

Comment: Java and JavaScript are **not** the same programming language. Could you be more clearer, and maybe include some code?

Comment: It is at the PDF Form. I want to write at the Custom Calculation Script, it says "Create and Edit Java Scripts". I`ve tried like this, but it didn`t work.

Comment: // build an array of field names to test;
var aMenu = new Array("Dropdown1", "Dropdown2","Dropdown3");
var count = 71; // count of field names
// loop through the array of field names one at time;
for(i = 0; i < a71; i++) {
// add 1 if equal else add zero
count += ("1" == this.getField(aMenu[i]).value? 1 : 0);
}
event.value = count;

Comment: Each Dropdown has 4 choices, so I made 4 text fields that I want to count how many times each option has been choosen.

Comment: Notice the space between Java and Scripts in that sentence. Also, I don't know where you got the `Create and Edit Java Scripts` from, **but I have found [this](http://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/print/how-to-do-not-so-simple-form-calculations), and it may help you.** Java and PDFs are completely separate things and ideas.